# Quicksort in VBA does not ignore case of letters

Tags: vba, quicksort

I was looking for a way to sort an array in VBA and found this [topic](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/string-manipulation.htm)

However, this function also differs between lower and uppercase letters.

Usually the word "also" comes before "apple" but when I use this quicksort with "also" and "APPLE" suddenly "APPLE" comes first.

Is this normal and if yes is there a way to ignore the case of letters?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `Option Compare Text` at the top of the QuickSort class/module. (This should be the very first line (or second line after `Option Explicit`) at the top of *all* of your code.)

The cause, of course, if because the ASCII values of "A" and "a" are different, as evidenced by doing the following in the immediate window:

```
? Asc("A")
 65 

? Asc("a")
 97
```

You see that "A" comes before "a".

Now, in the referenced QuickSort, you see that they are using inference comparisons, using the `>` or `<` type comparitors. This uses strict comparison of the Ascii values (above). `Option Compare Text` will force VBA to consider "a" = "A".

Try this following code, once before adding `Option Compare Text`, and once after.

```
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print "also" < "APPLE"
End Sub
```

Alternately, you could modify the QuickSort to be case-insensitive. You'd have to replace all the implicit comparitors (like `<` and `>=`) with the use of the `StrComp` function--being sure to include `vbTextCompare` as the thrid parameter.

For Example:

```
pivot < vArray(tmpHi)
```

...would be replaced with:

```
StrComp(pivot, vArray(tmpHi), vbTextCompare) < 0
```

Do some experimenting with the `StrComp` function. It may seem weird at first, but it's powerful and (I believe) faster than normal VBA String comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the expected behavior. In ASCII, capital letters come before lower case letters. You could use `UCASE` or `LCASE` around the comparisons:

```
 While (UCASE(vArray(tmpLow)) < UCASE(pivot) And tmpLow < inHi)
    tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
 Wend

 While (UCASE(pivot) < UCASE(vArray(tmpHi)) And tmpHi > inLow)
    tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
 Wend
```

I have no idea what the efficiency of such a comparison is, but I would bet it's rather negligible in the long run.

You could convert the case of pivot at the declaration, and you could also convert your array values as you add them to the array. The latter is probably your best solution as the conversion happens once. You've probably figured out that QuickSort is a recursive algorithm. Might as well remove the number of operations that have to occur with every call.